# Global Class Methods?

Tags: php, class

I want to be able to call my php class via an http post. So I came up with this.

```
$method = $_POST['method'];
$data = $_POST['data'];
$class_methods = get_class_methods('myclass');
if($method, $class_methods){
   $save = $myclass::$method($data);    
   echo $save;
}
```

Is there any global methods that exist on classes in general that might allow someone to call a method I have not defined?

Thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, have a look at:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php

Constructs like:

```
<?php
class Foo
{
    public static function bar() {
    }
}

$className = 'Foo';
$method = 'bar';

$return = call_user_func_array(array($className, $method), array() /* << the params go here */);
```

are also possible, and on PHP 5.3+ you can do:

```
$return = $className::$method();
```

directly.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should work for you

[__call and __callStatic](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#language.oop5.overloading.methods)

Answer (score 0):

There's a magic method `__call()` which is called when you try to invoke a method that hasn't been defined.

However, you need to explicitly assign that `__call()` method to your class otherwise you'll get an error that you're calling an undefined method.